# Will /etc/host file entries be transferred to VPN DNS Server?

Tags: vpn, localhost, host

I have several localhost entries on my local etc/host file. (in Mac "/etc/hosts" and in Windows "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

```
# LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
172.16.5.248 maxim.local
172.16.5.248 m.maxim.local
```

My Computer is connected to a VPN.

I want to know when I type "maxim.local" in my browser (i.e Chrome)

**Will the request go to the VPN DNS server? or will request will be handle locally only?**

Comment: **Will the request go to the VPN DNS server?** - No. That's the point of the hosts file. The name is resolved from the hosts file, not from your DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

The `hosts` file usually takes precedence.

On Linux with glibc (which is likely what you have), the order is defined in [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html). DNS resolution is handled either through the `dns` plugin or through the `systemd` plugin.